# How do URL fragment (the #stuff) interacts with CSS?

Tags: css, url, firefox, chromium

How does URL fragments interact with CSS? I have a page, say: `http://example.boom/is_this_a_bug.html`. The code for the page is shown in https://gist.github.com/3777018

When I load the page with the URL like that, the `.tab-pane` elements are not showed because they overflow their container, and it has an `overflow: hidden` property.

However, if I load the page by appending a valid fragment (`#00`) to the URL, then the `.tab-pane` gets visible, just as if the `left:100%` was not taken into account. Pressing the button just removes and resets `left:100%`, and then I get the overflowing tab-panes.

This happens in both Firefox 15.0.1 and Chromium 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is this a bug, or is documented elsewhere?

Best regards,

Manuel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a page with a fragment identifier in the URL, if that fragment identifier matches the ID of an element on the page the browser will scroll the page to bring that element into view.

Comment: But if the container has no scrolling, how this happens? Notice that the element that matches the fragment should be absolutely positioned with its left at 100% of the container, i.e, outside it box. Does this makes an scrolling? I think this is maybe a bug, cause `overflow: hidden` means do not scroll, isn't it?

Comment: `overflow:hidden` means things are not scrollable directly by the user, but still scrollable programmatically, as I recall.  So `overflow:hidden` things can definitely be scrolled from script.  Not sure about via scrolling to anchor as here, but I wouldn't be surprised if they are.

Comment: I will expand the gists to better show the problem, because if it's scrolling it's not working as I would expect.

Comment: That's exactly was it's happening. The gist now reflects that fact

Answer (score 0):

An alternative can be use javascript applied styles.

```
(function hashStyle() {

    if (window.location.hash == '#COLOR') {
        var css = document.createElement('style'),
            s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
            styles = 'body { background-color: #b0c4de; }';

        css.type = 'text/css';

        if (css.styleSheet) {
            css.styleSheet.cssText = styles;
        } else {
            css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));
        }
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(css, s);
    }
})();
```